# Youtube API v3 returning less then requested results

Tags: php, api, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API to request a set of videos I have maxResults set to 50 and in the returned object I get the following information: [totalResults] => 271 [resultsPerPage] => 50. All fine, but the object only holds 3 videos. When I use a search term with more results it does show more but still not the 50 that it should, only when a lot of videos are returned (say 1000+) then I get 50 in the object, what is going on here?

Here's my request code:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
'q' => "Let's Play The Legend of Zelda",
'maxResults' => 50,
'type' => 'video',
'videoEmbeddable' => 'true',
'publishedAfter' => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP",strtotime('-2 days')),
'videoDuration' => 'short',
'videoDefinition' => 'high',
'order' => 'viewCount',
));
```

And here is my returned object:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [pageInfo] => Array
        (
            [totalResults] => 972
            [resultsPerPage] => 50
        )
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            ...
            [7] => Array
        )
)
```

As you can see it only hold 8 videos while it has 972 results and should give me 50.

Comment: What exactly is your request?

Comment: I've updated the opening post with the request and the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with YouTube API. The `totalResults` value may returns not accurate numbers and it shouldn't be used to check how many results are in the response.

### Issue - API Member reply

> it's unfortunately a known issue, and in general, I would recommend treating totalResults as a very rough guide and ensure that you don't build any paging logic around it. The presence/absence of a nextPageToken in a response should be the only thing which indicates whether there are additional results available.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6125&can=1

What can you do in this situation is to use `count()` function to check how many items you've got.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem as the last commenter there. If I search on YouTube with the same parameters I'm a lot more results, but I guess it can't be helped.