# Youtube API video list returns less results than indicated

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am running a query on my own youtube channel to retrieve all the video titles. I have 680 videos but can only get about half of them. What I have done is create a code that iterates all the years since creation of the channel and within a year uses the pageTokens to go through the packs of 50 videos.

So a query would look like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={XXXXX}&channelId={XXXXX}&part=snippet,id&order=date&type=video&maxResults=50&publishedAfter=2018-01-01T00:00:00Z&publishedBefore=2019-01-01T00:00:00Z&pageToken=CDIQAA
```

In the results for these queries, I get the indication that there are the following contents:

```
array (
'totalResults' => 321,
'resultsPerPage' => 50,
),
```

Iterating through the pages, I get 2 pages filled with 50 items, then another one where the results show as well `'resultsPerPage' => 50,`  but contains only 35 videos, the rest for that year have 0 "items" in the JSON data. So the pages in question only give 135 results back instead of the 321. Once I switch to the next year, I get again 2 pages of full results, then one with some missing and then empty ones.

Any idea what could be wrong?

here is an excerpt of the last JSON data set:

```
array (
  'kind' => 'youtube#searchListResponse',
  'etag' => '"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/IsJyhRyDQ6qMmAHldktSRzEN2qs"',
  'nextPageToken' => 'CJYBEAA',
  'prevPageToken' => 'CGQQAQ',
  'regionCode' => 'DE',
  'pageInfo' => 
  array (
    'totalResults' => 321,
    'resultsPerPage' => 50,
  ),
  'items' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    [..contents..]
   35 =>
    [..last content and closing brackets..]
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674174/youtube-api-v3-returning-less-then-requested-results#22701076

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the entire video list of a given channel without any omissions, I suggest you to use [*PlaylistItems* endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) instead, queried for the given channel's uploads list by passing a proper value to the endpoint's *playlistId* parameter.

A given channel's uploads *playlistId* is obtained upon querying the [channel's own endpoint](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list). The needed ID is to be found at [`.items.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads). Usually, an channel ID and its corresponding uploads playlist ID are related by `s/^UC([0-9a-zA-Z_-]{22})$/UU\1/`.

One more remark: your should be aware of the [difference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt) between a video's published time and upload time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also could find this one here as an alternative explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387404