# YouTube Api V3 key limits and access not configured

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have found many suggestions and answers to the issue of receiving the error message from the youtube api i.e  [access not configured etc.] with the most prominent suggestions being: to delete the project, create a new project, enable the api and then create the key.

I did this a few times and it worked in general but after a while I am forced to do the same thing. Also I stop the process so as to not reach the quota limit but it seems like the API still restricts regardless of the actual quota.

For example, the key I am using has a quota of 10000 per day, from the api dashboard I see that I have reached that quota with 9816 units. My question is, if I have only made 283 requests to the api, how am I reaching 9816 units? Also has anyone found a consistent approach to using the API without reaching these limits and without have to regenerate a key.

I am just trying to understand the restrictions with this api.

```
{ "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "youtube.quota",    "reason": 
    "quotaExceeded"
```

and access not configured:

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
  {
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured",
"message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in 
 project 509865627602 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the fact that each API endpoint has attached a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost). Some endpoints are cheap, while others are expensive. Depending on usage patterns, [the default quotas](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) may put rather tight limits on the number of calls an user is allowed to make on various endpoints of the API.

For example querying the Search endpoint's `list` method for the `snippet` part has a quota cost of 100 units, while these applied on the PlaylistItems endpoint have a quota cost of only 3 units.

As a result (quoting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492980/8327971) to a related question), when one is interested for a given channel's uploaded videos playlist, he/she better use the latter endpoint (queried appropriatedly) instead of the former one.

To help you further, please elaborate about your API usage patterns.