# Streaming Youtube Live Video

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

"I'm designing an app where i need to call Live Video with specified Channel Id, but whenever i call Youtube Data api with Live parameter, it is returning blank fields.

Here is the link for google api explorer *** https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list ***

parameter for Live channel

channel Id *** UC5BMIWZe9isJXLZZWPWvBlg** 
Type  **Live ***

I have already tried with many channel with Live Video streaming but it always returns blank.

Answer (score 0):

There is something going wrong with the YouTube Data API. On the Deverloper Console under [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) it won't work if you are providing `channelId`. It will always return 0 results. I've tried this with several other channels who are live streaming right now.

There are several other people posting about this same issue. So we are not the only ones experiencing this issue. Google needs to fix something. Hopefully soon!

Comment: yes, its right so somehow we need to do workaround with other parameter of api.

Comment: @Roshan it looks like someone came up with [a pretty basic workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930207/youtube-data-api-no-longer-returns-active-live-streams-from-search-list/57982357#comment102424769_57934217) but it won't work for every person's use case.

Comment: its kind of a ok but i am thinking why youtube is not doing anything about this