# How to get live video id from YouTube channel

Tags: rest, google-api, youtube-api

YouTube API **eventType=live** not working, does anyone have an idea why?

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCmyKnNRH0wH-r8I-ceP-dsg&eventType=live&type=video&key=
```

Without `eventType` was working fine (but not now):

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCmyKnNRH0wH-r8I-ceP-dsg&autoplay=1
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? If no returned videos, it might be because there are no live videos right now.

Comment: check that chanel id live video is there..https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCmyKnNRH0wH-r8I-ceP-dsg&autoplay=1

Comment: Please edit your question and include your error message or a better description of the issue then "its not working"

Comment: no error message.. just not work before comments pls check code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like YouTube changed something in API, search.list really not returning live broadcast since end of last week.

**If you have user's access token** you can use `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet&broadcastStatus=active&broadcastType=all`
 endpoint to retrieve if any broadcast is live.

**If you do not have user's access token**, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57934217/12071103) answer 
but i didn't check it if it is working

Anyway this question looks like to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930207/youtube-data-api-no-longer-returns-active-live-streams-from-search-list) question

Answer (score 0):

Right now the YouTube API is not working, specifically for retrieving live streams of a specific channelId. In other words if you are setting `channelId` in the API call, you will get 0 results.

If you're using an API key rather than OAuth (not sure if OAuth works) the only work around at the moment is to use the API to search for a specific title. Here is my query URL below.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&type=video&maxResults=20&order=date&q=My+Uniquely+Titled+Livestream&key=[apiKey]

The results returned by the API will be from all of YouTube. (Note: the rest is done serverside) Put the results into an array and discard any that don't match your `channelId`. Then check the titles in an array and only get the video ID of the one that matches your desired title. That is the basic logic and it is sort of a rigid work around that won't work for most. But at least it will get you what you need until Google fixes the API.