# YouTube's Data APi V3 search.list returns no video in "items"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Until last two weeks my API calls returned my upcoming videos, but then it is returning an empty list.
What I'm doing wrong?

Call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&maxResults=50&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Although there are videos on the Channel, it always returns empty items:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/l3G5k1irnfv6llZ4MGNRwQRrUpc\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
 "regionCode": "ES",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1273,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you Jorge try to run *your program* with a channel other than yours?

Comment: I answered the same issue here. That should work for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171867/youtube-api-not-listing-all-videos-from-channel

Comment: @stvar If I use the code of another channel it works without problems. Is it a wrong configuration with the channel?

Comment: @Jorge Castro: It may very well be and somehow you'll have to get to that. Have you tried to use the Youtube's Web UI to search for videos belonging to your channel? If that's not going to work, then there's something wrong with your channel. Be kind to keep us informed, as it may help other SO users too.

Comment: @stvar Youtube's Web UI find videos belonging our channel

Comment: @Jorge Castro: Could then try to replace within *your program* the code querying the Search endpoint with one that uses the PlaylistItems endpoint queried for your channel's [uploads playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492980/8327971)? If that won't work either I suggest to test your program with a different API key (after all, maybe the problem is with your key).