# YouTube API not listing all videos from channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube Data API to get info about videos from a channel. The API response is not including all the videos that are uploaded to the respective channel.

This is the channel (right now it has 6 videos):
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdSjDEx46aNP0oKPN_J6hOA/videos

Video list (right now): https://i.ibb.co/K91bJxS/image.png

Here is my API call: 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&key=API_KEY&maxResults=15&channelId=UCdSjDEx46aNP0oKPN_J6hOA&order=date

Here is the response (only 4 videos listed):

> { 
>       "kind":"youtube#searchListResponse",
>       "etag":"\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/be7hxSCsiJnKBCJePUfIg5bfJO4\"",
>       "regionCode":"RO",
>       "pageInfo":{ 
>           "totalResults":4,
>           "resultsPerPage":15
>       },
>       "items":[ 
>           { 
>               "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
>               "etag":"\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/ntdnt3QTuNN5l9_iYJAAgH4kE-w\"",
>               "id":{ 
>                   "kind":"youtube#video",
>                   "videoId":"GkYNJH0qkKc"
>               },
>               "snippet":{ 
>                   "publishedAt":"2019-09-29T07:47:58.000Z",
>                   "channelId":"UCdSjDEx46aNP0oKPN_J6hOA",
>                   "title":"Tutorial comentado 3/3",
>                   "description":"Comentamos el tutorial de MTG Arena para quien no lo haya jugado nunca. Damos explicaciones útiles para jugadores noveles.",
>                   "thumbnails":{ 
>                       "default":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GkYNJH0qkKc/default.jpg",
>                           "width":120,
>                           "height":90
>                       },
>                       "medium":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GkYNJH0qkKc/mqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":320,
>                           "height":180
>                       },
>                       "high":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GkYNJH0qkKc/hqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":480,
>                           "height":360
>                       }
>                   },
>                   "channelTitle":"Car Bar",
>                   "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
>               }
>           },
>           { 
>               "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
>               "etag":"\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/w_3YGOA4SdmMgL15Fzg1qQaAQQo\"",
>               "id":{ 
>                   "kind":"youtube#video",
>                   "videoId":"OHLTiXWJ9pM"
>               },
>               "snippet":{ 
>                   "publishedAt":"2019-09-29T07:44:03.000Z",
>                   "channelId":"UCdSjDEx46aNP0oKPN_J6hOA",
>                   "title":"Tutorial comentado 2/3",
>                   "description":"Comentamos el tutorial de MTG Arena para quien no lo haya jugado nunca. Damos explicaciones útiles para jugadores noveles.",
>                   "thumbnails":{ 
>                       "default":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OHLTiXWJ9pM/default.jpg",
>                           "width":120,
>                           "height":90
>                       },
>                       "medium":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OHLTiXWJ9pM/mqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":320,
>                           "height":180
>                       },
>                       "high":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OHLTiXWJ9pM/hqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":480,
>                           "height":360
>                       }
>                   },
>                   "channelTitle":"Car Bar",
>                   "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
>               }
>           },
>           { 
>               "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
>               "etag":"\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/RE4dR9kF05E34eOpiVOGKgkIs4g\"",
>               "id":{ 
>                   "kind":"youtube#video",
>                   "videoId":"j9QQVjakiCM"
>               },
>               "snippet":{ 
>                   "publishedAt":"2019-09-29T07:25:42.000Z",
>                   "channelId":"UCdSjDEx46aNP0oKPN_J6hOA",
>                   "title":"Tutorial comentado 1/3",
>                   "description":"Comentamos el tutorial de MTG Arena para quien no lo haya jugado nunca. Damos explicaciones útiles para jugadores noveles.",
>                   "thumbnails":{ 
>                       "default":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j9QQVjakiCM/default.jpg",
>                           "width":120,
>                           "height":90
>                       },
>                       "medium":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j9QQVjakiCM/mqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":320,
>                           "height":180
>                       },
>                       "high":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j9QQVjakiCM/hqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":480,
>                           "height":360
>                       }
>                   },
>                   "channelTitle":"Car Bar",
>                   "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
>               }
>           },
>           { 
>               "kind":"youtube#searchResult",
>               "etag":"\"p4VTdlkQv3HQeTEaXgvLePAydmU/56JGSQ25cLzFPdVa5Mk-Y63hHC0\"",
>               "id":{ 
>                   "kind":"youtube#video",
>                   "videoId":"46dml09YB1E"
>               },
>               "snippet":{ 
>                   "publishedAt":"2019-09-28T07:30:01.000Z",
>                   "channelId":"UCdSjDEx46aNP0oKPN_J6hOA",
>                   "title":"Presentacion Version Septiembre 2019",
>                   "description":"Revisamos las novedades de esta nueva versión, la 1.0 oficial de MTG Arena.",
>                   "thumbnails":{ 
>                       "default":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/46dml09YB1E/default.jpg",
>                           "width":120,
>                           "height":90
>                       },
>                       "medium":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/46dml09YB1E/mqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":320,
>                           "height":180
>                       },
>                       "high":{ 
>                           "url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/46dml09YB1E/hqdefault.jpg",
>                           "width":480,
>                           "height":360
>                       }
>                   },
>                   "channelTitle":"Car Bar",
>                   "liveBroadcastContent":"none"
>               }
>           }
>       ]
>   }

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Lately the Search endpoint seems to not work OK. Just browse down the list of `youtube-data-api` tag on this forum to find more info. However, for querying the uploads playlist of a channel better change your method: use [PlaylistItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492980/8327971) endpoint instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated from this [answer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141255579#comment15) in the issuetracker

You may use the following series of call as a workaround:

> 1) Get the upload playlist using Channels.list:
>
> https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=contentDetails&id=UCupvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw&fields=items(contentDetails%252FrelatedPlaylists%252Fuploads%252Cid)&_h=12&
>
> 2) Then use playlistitems.list to get the latest videos:
>
> https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=UUHnyfMqiRRG1u-2MsSQLbXA&_h=6&

That series of call is also more efficient as it uses 90% less quota.