# question regarding quota youtube data api

Tags: react-native, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a question regarding the quota of the youtube data api. Currently I am getting all videos from a youtube channel I own (about 50 videos), using the youtube data api via react native.

When I check the quota, I see 100 queries used, and I know it is my own, but what I don't understand is why already 100 and not 1. Can someone explain why that is? Because in that way the quota (per day) is gone soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it that you use the [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint? This is known (see the linked doc) to be quite expensive: each call of it has a quota cost of 100 units! I suspect that you do confuse the 100 units of quota cost of one query with an actual number of 100 queries each of one unit cost.

**Update:**

Since confirming that you use the `Search.list` endpoint, I recommend to replace it with an inexpensive one: the [PlaylistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint queried appropriately that have a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of only 3 units. For that go see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492980/8327971) to a related question.

Comment: Yes, I use the search endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=.....&channelId=........&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20